# How to combine fields with duplicate keys, to comma separated

Tags: r, string, key

I have a data.frame that has a key, `fignum` and a data field, `codefile`, but where `fignum` may be duplicated.

Where duplicates occur, I want to combine the `codefile` data fields into a single row, separated by `,`.  Here's my input:

```
> cf
   fignum                       codefile
8     4.6           04_6-cholera-water.R
9     P.3 04_P3a-cholera-neighborhoods.R
10    P.3       04_P3b-SnowMap-density.R
11    5.5    05_5-playfair-east-indies.R

> duplicated(cf[,"fignum"])
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The desired output combines the two "P.3" `codefile` values into one observation, to look like this:

```
> cf-wanted
   fignum                                                  codefile
8     4.6                                      04_6-cholera-water.R
9     P.3  04_P3a-cholera-neighborhoods.R, 04_P3b-SnowMap-density.R
10    5.5                               05_5-playfair-east-indies.R
```

Answer (score 2):

We could `group_by` by `fignum` and summarise

```
library(dplyr)
cf %>% 
  group_by(fignum) %>% 
  summarise(codefile = paste0(codefile, collapse = ', '), .groups = 'drop')
```

```
fignum codefile                                                
  <chr>  <chr>                                                   
1 4.6    04_6-cholera-water.R                                    
2 5.5    05_5-playfair-east-indies.R                             
3 P.3    04_P3a-cholera-neighborhoods.R, 04_P3b-SnowMap-density.R
```